# Using constant in CUDA kernel: works with int, fails to compile with float

Tags: cuda

Referencing an `int` constant from CUDA kernel compiles and works correctly, but referencing `float` constant produces a compilation error.

Here is the minimum code to reproduce this, compiled on Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2013, using CUDA 6.5:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>

const int foo = 42;
const float bar = 42.0f;

__global__ void kernel(void)
{
  printf("foo = %d\n", foo);  // OK
  printf("bar = %f\n", bar);  // error : identifier "bar" is undefined in device code
}

int main()
{
  kernel <<<1, 1 >>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error : identifier "bar" is undefined in device code
```

Note: If the second `printf` line is commented out, the code compiles and produces the expected output of `42`. Runtime error checking is skipped for clarity, since this question is about compile time error.

I know I can use CUDA `__constant__` memory to achieve similar goal, but still I would like to understand what causes the difference between `int` and `float` in this scenario, and whether there is a way to make kernel code using `float` constant compilable.

Comment: this is a good explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004955/host-float-constant-usage-in-a-kernel-in-cuda

Comment: @V_Maenolis, thanks, this is a good explanation indeed. Seems like this all boils down to "int can be optimized more aggressively than float", and this optimization is implementation-dependent.

Comment: In my case it worked both for the integer, as well as for the float variable.The program gave this output: `foo = 42 bar = 42.000000`.
A first guess is that this is because I'm working on an integrated device (Jetson TK1) and the host and device memories actually coincide (to some extent). I can't tell why it worked on for your float but not for your int variable. I think, however, that `const` variables are not accessible from the device, or at least I can't find a reference in the CUDA programming guide. I hope someone can offer more information.