# variable declared in .cuh file is undefined in .cu

Tags: cuda

I try to write a project on CUDA and I have several constants I want to use without passing them back and forth.

I have a Settings.cuh file looking like

```
#ifndef _SETTINGS_
#define _SETTINGS_
#include <math.h>
#define sqr(a) ((a)*(a))

const float START_X = -1.5;
const float START_Y = 0;
const float START_Z = 0;
const float Delta = 0.1;
const float Epsilon = 0.015;
const float Low = 0.01;
const float Sigma = -log(Low) / sqr(Epsilon - Delta);
const float fx = 525;
const float fy = 525;
const float cx = 319.5;
const float cy = 239.5;

#endif
```

and here is a device function which can't read fx:

```
__device__ int2 getProjection(const float3 &xLocal, const float FX, const float FY, const float CX, const float CY){
    //Might be the case that it is unnecessary to send in FX.
    float x = fx*xLocal.x / xLocal.z + cx;
    float y = fy *xLocal.y / xLocal.z + cy;
    int2 tmp = { round(x), round(y) };
    return tmp;
}
```

When I include this in .cu file and if I try to use this in a **device** function I get the error identifier fx is undefined in device code. I have tried both .cuh and just .h extension, but none of it works. I have some old code which have compiled and run, and there I just have a file parameters.cuh from which I can reach all constants, both on host and device.

Of course, I could use FX instead, but the main issue is that it can't see the variables in the Settings.cuh file.

Previously, I used Linux, but now I am using windows visual studio instead.

Comment: `_SETTINGS_` and `_SETTIGNS_` are not the same thing....

Comment: Fixed, but that was just a typo here.

Comment: OK, so please post a more complete example. It is impossible to say anything about what might be wrong based on a four line code snippet, one of which contained a syntax error....

Comment: You cannot use an ordinary global or static variable in `__device__` or `__global__` functions.    If you don't intend to change this value, you can put `const` in front of it, then [it should be usable in device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#const-variables).

Comment: Strange, I have const in front of the variables, sorry I did not provide more code. Thought a simple example would make it easier.

Comment: What you have posted now works fine for me on linux.  [here](http://pastebin.com/4sjNcJ3V) is an example.  I'm pretty sure this should work on windows as well.  You still haven't provided an MCVE however.  What is the exact compile command being issued?  What is the exact error output?  Can you reproduce that error using just the files I have shown in my example?

Comment: I think I had the same problem - check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443857/using-constant-in-cuda-kernel-works-with-int-fails-to-compile-with-float

Comment: So it seems one cannot rely on that to work? It might work on some computers and some not?